# javascript / nodejs: synchronously calling set of similar asynchronous functions on large, chunked data set causes memory leak

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, memory-leaks

I will try to simplify and explain my issue:

I am attempting to take a large database (mysql) of entries (1,000,000+) and reindex everything in another database (elasticsearch). In order to do this successfully I have to break the entries up into chunks to send reasonably sized requests to the new db and not load too much into memory at once (I don't have limitless memory on my server).

Here are three different versions of attempted solutions that all lead to similiar memory leaks (usage just keeps growing past 1gb until the script is finished):

1.

```
function sync(start_id) {
    get_messages_from_db(start_id, function(messages){

        if (messages.length == 0) return undefined;

        index_in_elastic_search(messages, function(){
            next_start_id = message.last.id
            setTimeout(function(){
               sync(next_start_id)
            }, 0);
        });
    });
}

sync(0)
```

2.

```
start_ids = [0, 100, 200... 1000000]
requests_to_sync = []
start_ids.forEach(function(id){
    requests_to_sync.push(get_messages_from_db.bind(undefined, id))
});

function sync_requests(requests) {

    if (requests.length == 0) return undefined;

    requests.shift()(function(messages){
        index_in_elastic_search(messages, function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                sync_requests(requests);
            },0);
        });
    });
}

sync_requests(requests_to_sync);
```

finally I tried the node async library because I thought they might have solved this problem

3.

```
start_ids = [0, 100, 200... 1000000]
async.series(start_ids, function(id, next){
    get_messages(id, function(messages){
        index_in_elastic_search(messages, function(){
            next();
        });
    });
});
```

So yeah, each of these solutions is similar. In practice they all take about the same amount of time to execute, and all lead to a memory leak.

I'm guessing the leak has to do with references to `messages` not being cleared properly at each iteration and probably something to do with recursion.

If anyone can shed light on why the heap keeps growing, or how I can fix this... that would be great.

Comment: what is the size of the JSON returned in the callback? there is a limit to the JSON size approx 4MB and nesting should not exceed 64 levels which beyond is unstable. I would urge you to use delete keyword to free the memory once done with your data chunk.

Comment: @ Nirus I should have mentioned, I have attemted to clear messages with `delete messages` and `messages = []` and `messages = null` but that has no effect. And yes, the response is much smaller than 4MB, which was one of the reasons for chunking up messages in the first place. I read somewhere that V8 is probably saving references to the callback/closures themselves which have their own scoped copy of `messages` that is distinct in memory from the explicit `messages` in the script.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Closure tend to save the data references. Why dont you use getter/setter methods to access the `message` variable. By this you will be reusing the same variable from the single closure scope instead of nesting functions creating a undesirable closure effect as in your case. + read these: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management  and  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/

Comment: @Nirus hmm, that sounds promising. Thanks, I'll take a look and report back.

Comment: hope this solves your problem. Please report back, i am curious too..

Answer (score 1):

Dayum, 1 million records.  So, I'm guessing the garbage collector is practically never getting a chance to do any work.  I'm not like a guru on how js garbage collection works, but I know a lil bit. For something like this, I would try to avoid making functions.  I always consider function creation a costly process, both in terms of memory and cpu usage.  So... maybe try something a bit more spread out like:

```
/* globals get_messages, index_in_elastic_search */

var state = {
    curr_id: 0,
    messages: null,
    next_func: null
};

get_more_messages();

function get_more_messages() {

    get_messages( state.curr_id, on_messages ); 

}

function on_messages(messages) {

    if( messages.length ) {

        delete state.messages; // this might help, maybe not

        state.messages = messages; // this is probably sufficient to start garbage collection of the old messages
        state.next_func = process_messages;

        gc_love();

    } else {
        // maybe call state.done() here as a final callback
    }

}

function process_messages() {

    state.curr_id = state.messages[messages.length-1].id;
    state.next_func = get_more_messages;
    index_in_elastic_search(messages, gc_love ); // wait 20 ms and call get_more_messages

}

function gc_love() {

    setTimeout(state.next_func, 20);

}
```

So we're only ever creating 4 functions and 1 object here.  If you use all those closures, you're creating quite a bit more functions and creating a lot more work for js scoping, which is never a good thing.

Comment: You can play with 20 ms and try more or less.

Comment: insightful answer, thank you. Also, why not just use 0? As I understand it we  use setTimeout to reset the stack, so does it really matter how long the timeout is?

Comment: 20 ms is the time you're giving the processor to do background things, namely allowing the browser's javascript engine to get some garbage collection done.  You can try with 0, in fact, you SHOULD start with 0.  But if you're running out of memory, try 10-50 ms, to give some processor to js gc.  If that doesn't work, then you might be dealing with some libraries written by overzealous closure programmers.